# See all classes and interfaces that an object can be said to be an instance of

Tags: php, reflection

Is there a simple way to take any object and get a full list of all classes and interfaces that will return `true` when compared with `instanceof`?

Comment: No it isn't. When you have an object of type `T` at runtime, it may be of another type extending `T`.

Comment: Sorry, I might not be following. How does this fit in with the [code below](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30734309/see-all-classes-and-interfaces-that-an-object-can-be-said-to-be-an-instance-of#30734310)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might not be the best way (or even the right way), but while trying to find the answer for this question myself, I came up with this function:

```
function getAllTypes($object) {
    $reflection = new ReflectionObject($object);
    $types = $reflection->getInterfaceNames();
    $types[] = get_class($object);
    while($reflection = $reflection->getParentClass()) {
        $types[] = $reflection->getName();
    }
    return $types;
}
```

I then tested it with

```
// Fake classes and interfaces
interface Interface1 {};
interface Interface2 {};
interface Interface3 {};
abstract class Abstract1 implements Interface1 {};
class Class1 extends Abstract1 implements Interface2 {}
class Class2 extends Class1 implements Interface3 {}

// Instantiated object
$testObject = new Class2();

// Test instance of
echo $testObject instanceof Class2 ? '.' : 'X';
echo $testObject instanceof Class1 ? '.' : 'X';
echo $testObject instanceof Abstract1 ? '.' : 'X';
echo $testObject instanceof Interface3 ? '.' : 'X';
echo $testObject instanceof Interface2 ? '.' : 'X';
echo $testObject instanceof Interface1 ? '.' : 'X';
echo PHP_EOL;

// Print all Types
$types = getAllTypes($testObject);
foreach($types as $type) {
    echo $type.PHP_EOL;
}
```

Running in the console gives this:

```
$ php test.php
......
Interface2
Interface1
Interface3
Class2
Class1
Abstract1
```

Is this the best way? Have I missed anything?

**Edit:**

An even easier way of doing the above without using Reflection:

```
function getAllTypesEasy($object) {
    return array_merge(
        [get_class($object)],
        class_parents($object),
        class_implements($object)
    );
}
```

**Edit 2:**

Without writing all the code here (see the link), further investigation shows you ***do*** need to use Reflection if you want to get all of the Traits used to build an object. Additionally HHVM and PHP order the results slightly differently:

http://3v4l.org/vWOmn